# Determine all the factorizations of $f(x)=x$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the polynomial $f(x) = x$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}[x]$, which is reducible as it factors as $(3x+4)(4x+3)$.

Determine all the factorizations of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}[x]$. [Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.]

I'm having trouble with this. We know the factorization of $f(x)$ modulo $(2)$ must be $1 \cdot x$ and the factorization of $f(x)$ modulo $(3)$ is also $1 \cdot x$ since $f(x)$ is irreducible in these fields. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem we know $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. We can make a homomorphism

\begin{align}
\phi: \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}[x] &\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x] \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x] \\
p(x) &\mapsto (p(x)+(2), \ p(x)+(3)).
\end{align}

I don't know what to do from here, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}
$$

The image of $x$ under the homomorphism you gave is the pair $(x, x)$. Since $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ are fields, the polynomial $x$ is irreducible over them (degree), and so this pair can be factored in a total of four ways (where we are counting $2x\cdot2$ and $x\cdot1$ as different factorizations in $\Z/3\Z$ i.e. we are not ignoring units):
$$
(1, 1) \cdot (x, x) \hspace{1pc} (1, 2) \cdot (x, 2x) \hspace{1pc} (1, x) \cdot(x, 1) \hspace{1pc} (x, 2) \cdot (1, 2x)
$$
Now we have to lift these factorizations to $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}[x]$, i.e. invert the CRT isomorphism, which is the fun part. Note that under the map
$$
\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \to \Z/2\Z \times \Z/3\Z
$$
the image of $3$ is $(1, 0)$ and the image of $4$ is $(0, 1)$. Therefore, the inverse of this map must be $(a, b) \mapsto 3a + 4b \mod 6$. So our factorizations lift to:
$$
1\cdot x \hspace{1pc} 5(5x) \hspace{1pc} (3 + 4x)(3x + 4) \hspace{1pc} (3x+2)(3+2x).
$$
(Again, two of these factorizations only differ by the unit $5 \in \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, so should probably be counted as the same.)

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. May I ask, what was your motive for counting $2x\cdot 2$ and $x \cdot  1$ as different factorizations in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]$? Was it because we couldn't know beforehand that the output of the inverse map would still be a unit multiple in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: @antsatsui no, i guess we do know that it will just be a unit, the point being that $(1, 2)$ is a unit in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ (it's the image of $5$ under the CRT map). But I wasn't sure if your question wanted all factorizations or just factorizations up to units (the latter question is the more natural one).

Comment: As long as we consider factorizations differing by a unit distinct, also $5(3x+4)(2x+3)$, $5(3x+2)(4x+3)$ can be added to the given list.