# Factorization of $f(x)=x$ in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$ where $n$ is the product of $k$ distinct primes (considering $\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}[x]$ as example)

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring, polynomial-rings

### Intro

This is the final part of the problem 9.4.20 (e), (d) from *Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra*. They formulate it as "Determine all the factorizations of $f(x)=x$ in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$ where $n$ is the product of $k$ distinct primes" and ask to show that $x=(10x+21)(15x+16)(6x+25)$ in $\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

$\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$ is *not an integral domain* when $k>1$.

The simplest case when $n=6=2\cdot3$, so that $x$ is factorized in $\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}[x]$  was previously considered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662649/determine-all-the-factorizations-of-fx-x-in-mathbbz-6-mathbbzx), but the proposed solution "$1⋅x,\ 5(5x),\ (3+4x)(3x+4),\ (3x+2)(3+2x)$" is *not entirely correct*. 
${1,5}$ are units in $\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}[x]$. 
If we are to list *all* the factorizations, then also $5(3x+4)(2x+3),\ 5(3x+2)(4x+3)$ should be *added* to the given list. 
If we are to list *only* the factorizations *unique up to multiplication by units*, then together with an obvious $5(5x)$ (which the author did mention) one of the other two factorizations, say $(3x+2)(3+2x)$, must be *excluded* from the given list, because $(3+4x)(3x+4)=1\cdot(3+4x)(3x+4)=5\cdot5\cdot(3+4x)(3x+4)=(5(3+4x))(5(3x+4))=(15+20x)(15x+20)=(3+2x)(3x+2)$ in $\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

⦁ I constrain the argument to *factorization with maximal number of nonconstant factors unique up to multiplication by units* (up to associates) since other factorizations (with less number of nonconstant factors) can be obtained from it. I decided to first explore the general case $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$ and then apply its results to $\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}[x]$. By "associates" below I mean their usual definition.

---

---

### Part 1

Let $n=p_a p_b…p_j p_k$ with $p_i$-s being distinct primes in $\Bbb{Z}$ numbered alphabetically. According to Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT), $$\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]≅\Bbb{Z}/p_a \Bbb{Z}[x]×\Bbb{Z}/p_b \Bbb{Z}[x]×…×\Bbb{Z}/p_k \Bbb{Z}[x]$$(this is almost trivial to show so I omit the proof). Denote this isomorphism as $π$. 
The mapping of  $x=(1\ mod\ n)x∈\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$ under $π$ is $(1\ mod \ n)x↔((1\ mod\ p_a )x,\ (1\ mod\ p_b )x,\ …,\ (1\ mod\ p_k )x)$ or $$x↔(x,x,…,x)$$
hence the image $\overline{f(x)}$ of $f(x)=x$ in all the quotient rings $\Bbb{Z}/p_i\Bbb{Z}[x]$ is $\overline{f(x)}=x$.

**Claim 1:** $f(x)=x$ has *no* factor of degree $≥2$ in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$. 
Suppose the contrary: $f(x)=x$ has a factor of degree $≥2$. Then the leading coefficient $K$ of this factor is nonzero in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, hence there is at least one prime $p_i$ such that $p_i∤K$ in $\Bbb{Z}$, therefore $K∉(p_i)$. Then in the field $\Bbb{Z}/(p_i)=\Bbb{Z}/p_i\Bbb{Z}$ we have that $K≠0$, hence (because there are no zero divisors in a field) $deg⁡\ \overline{f(x)}>1$ in $\Bbb{Z}/p_i\Bbb{Z}[x]$, hence $\overline{f(x)}≠x$, a contradiction. ◼

So, the factorization of $x$ in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$ can be written as:
$$x=C(a_1 x+a_0 )(b_1 x+b_0 )(c_1 x+c_0 )…$$
where $C$ is some constant polynomial, i.e., $C∈\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$.

**Claim 2:** The constant factor $C$ in the factorization of $x$ in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$ is a unit in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$. 
Note that $C∉(p_i)$ for each prime $p_i$ since otherwise there would be $\overline{C}=\overline{0}$ in the field $\Bbb{Z}/(p_i)=\Bbb{Z}/p_i\Bbb{Z}$ and hence $x=\overline{0}(\overline{a_1}x+\overline{a_0})(\overline{b_1}x+\overline{b_0})…=\overline{0}$ in $\Bbb{Z}/p_i\Bbb{Z}[x]$, a contradiction. Therefore, $p_i∤C$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}$ for all primes $p_i$ so that $g.c.d.(C,n)=1$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}$, hence $C∈(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^×$, i.e., $C$ is a unit in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$. ◼

Therefore, taking any factor $f_1x+f_0$ in the factorization of $x$ we can write $x=C(a_1 x+a_0 )(b_1 x+b_0 )...(f_1 x+c_f )…=(a_1 x+a_0 )(b_1 x+b_0 )...(C(f_1 x+f_0 ))…=(a_1 x+a_0 )(b_1 x+b_0 )...(Cf_1 x+Cf_0)...=(a_1 x+a_0 )(b_1 x+b_0 )...$ with $Cf_1 x+Cf_0$ being *associate* to $f_1 x+f_0$. So, *up to associates* of its factors $x$ in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$ can be written as                                                                                               $$x=(a_1 x+a_0 )(b_1 x+b_0 )(c_1 x+c_0 )…$$,
i.e., with the constant factor being $1$.

**Claim 3:** $x$ has at most $k$ nonconstant factors in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$. 
The isomorphism $π$ maps $x$ to the $k$-tuple $(x,x,…,x)$ with each $i$-th coordinate $x∈\Bbb{Z}/p_i\Bbb{Z}[x]$. This $k$-tuple can be written as a product of at most $k$ nonconstant tuples-factors in $\Bbb{Z}/p_a \Bbb{Z}[x]×\Bbb{Z}/p_b \Bbb{Z}[x]×…×\Bbb{Z}/p_k\Bbb{Z}[x]$, since otherwise (because all $\Bbb{Z}/p_i\Bbb{Z}$ are fields) at least one coordinate of our $k$-tuple $(x,x,…,x)$ would be of degree $>1$ hence $≠x$, a contradiction. So, $(x,x,…,x)$ has at most $k$ nonconstant factors in $\Bbb{Z}/p_a \Bbb{Z}[x]×\Bbb{Z}/p_b \Bbb{Z}[x]×…×\Bbb{Z}/p_k\Bbb{Z}[x]$, hence by the isomorphism $π$ follows that $x$ has at most $k$ nonconstant factors in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$. ◼

So, up to associates a factorization of $x$ in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$ can be written as:
$$x=(a_1 x+a_0)(b_1 x+b_0)…(k_1 x+k_0)$$

Let $(x,x,…,x)$ be a product of maximal possible number $k$ of nonconstant factors in $\Bbb{Z}/p_a \Bbb{Z}[x]×\Bbb{Z}/p_b \Bbb{Z}[x]×…×\Bbb{Z}/p_k\Bbb{Z}[x]$, i.e., $(x,x,…,x)=q_a (x) q_b (x)…q_k (x)$, where $q_i(x)$ is a $k$-tuple. Since $\Bbb{Z}/p_i\Bbb{Z}$ are fields and so contain no zero divisors, we necessarily have $q_i(x)=(C_a,C_b,…,C_h,C_ix,C_j,…,C_k)$  [after renumbering $q_i(x)$-s if necessary so as to have exactly $i$-th coordinate nonconstant in each $q_i(x)$], that is,  *only one coordinate is nonconstant and for any pair $q_i (x),q_j (x)$ the non-constant coordinates $i,j$ are distinct*; furthermore, this *nonconstant coordinate is necessarily of degree 1 and has no constant term*, i.e., is exactly of the form $C_i x$.
Thus,
$$(x,x,…,x)=(C_{1a} x, C_{1b},…,C_{1k})(C_{2a}, C_{2b}x,…,C_{2k})…(C_{sa},C_{sb},…,C_{sk} x) ⇔ \\ (x,x,…,x)=(\prod C_{ia},\prod C_{ib},...,\prod C_{ik})(x, 1, …, 1)(1, x, 1,…,1)…(1, 1, …, 1, x)$$
where $C_{if}$ is a unit in $\Bbb{Z}/p_f\Bbb{Z}$ (because $\Bbb{Z}/p_f\Bbb{Z}$ is a field), so that $(\prod C_{ia},\prod C_{ib},...,\prod C_{ik})=u$ is a *unit* in  $\Bbb{Z}/p_a \Bbb{Z}[x]×\Bbb{Z}/p_b \Bbb{Z}[x]×…×\Bbb{Z}/p_k\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

So the mapping $x↔(x,x,…,x)$ by the isomorphism $π$ can be written as: $$1(a_1 x+a_0)(b_1 x+b_0)…(k_1 x+k_0)=u(x, 1, …, 1)(1, x, 1,…,1)…(1, 1, …, 1, x)$$
Since isomorphism maps units to units, $1↔u$. Since isomorphism maps identity to identity, it can only be that  $1↔(1,…,1)$, so that $u=(1,…,1)$.

⦁ Thus, when considering factorizations of $x$ in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$ *unique up to associates*, the mapping $x↔(x,x,…,x)$ performed by the isomorphism $π$ can be considered as: $$(a_1 x+a_0 )(b_1 x+b_0 )…(k_1 x+k_0 )↔(x,1,…,1)(1,x,1,…,1)…(1,…,1,x)\    [map]$$ where *each factor* $f_1 x+f_0$ *on the left is mapped* ***bijectively*** (because of the isomorphism) *to some $k$-tuple on the right*. Therefore, **if $n=p_a p_b…p_j p_k$, there is only one unique up to associates factorization of $x$ in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$ with maximal possible number $k$ of factors**. [result]

---

Now our goal is to find these factors. Consider any factor $f_1x+f_0$. The isomorphism $π$ maps it as $$f_1x+f_0↔(\ (f_1+ (p_a) )x+f_0+ (p_a),… ,(f_1+ (p_f) )x+f_0+ (p_f) ,…  ,(f_1+ (p_k) )x+f_0+(p_k)\ )  ⇔ \\  f_1x+f_0↔(\ (f_1\ mod\ p_a )x+f_0\ mod\ p_a,… ,(f_1\ mod\ p_f\ )x+f_0\ mod\ p_f,…  ,(f_1\ mod\ p_k )x+f_0\ mod\ p_k)\ )$$
where the ideals $(p_i)$ are ideals in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$.

Since each $k$-tuple on the right of the $[map]$ above has exactly one nonconstant coordinate $x$ and all the other coordinates equal to $1$, there is exactly one prime, say $p_f$ (after renaming if necessary), such that $f_1∉(p_f)$, furthermore, $f_1≡1\ (mod\ p_f)$, whereas $f_1∈(p_a), (p_b),…,(p_e), (p_g),…,(p_k)$, so that $f_1∈(p_a)⋂ (p_b)⋂…⋂(p_e)⋂(p_g)⋂…⋂(p_k)$, or, since the ideals $(p_a), (p_b),…,(p_e), (p_g),…,(p_k)$ are pairwise comaximal in the commutative ring $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, $f_1∈(p_a)(p_b)…(p_e)(p_g)…(p_k)=(p_ap_b…p_ep_g…p_k)$. So, $f_1=p_ap_b…p_ep_g…p_kα$ for some $α∈\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, hence $p_ap_b…p_ep_g…p_kα≡1\ (mod\ p_f)$, therefore, both $p_a p_b…p_e p_g…p_k,α∈(\Bbb{Z}/p_f\Bbb{Z})^×$. Since $α∈\Bbb{Z}/p_f\Bbb{Z}$, also $α∈\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ and we can find it as $α=(p_a p_b…p_e p_g…p_k )^{-1}\ mod\ p_f$, the multiplicative inverse of $p_a p_b…p_e p_g…p_k$ modulo $p_f$.

For the similar reason, $f_0∈(p_f)$, whereas $f_0∉(p_a), (p_b),…,(p_e), (p_g),…,(p_k)$, furthermore, $f_0≡1\ (mod\ p_i)\ ∀i≠f$. The ideals $(p_f ),(p_a p_b…p_e p_g…p_k)$ are comaximal in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, therefore, $(p_f )+(p_a p_b…p_e p_g…p_k)=(1)$, hence $p_f γ-p_a p_b…p_e p_g…p_k β=1$ for some $β,γ∈\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, hence                                        $p_f γ=p_a p_b…p_e p_g…p_k β+1$.Therefore, $p_f γ≡1\ (mod\ p_i )\ ∀i≠f$, so that $p_f γ$ satisfies the requirements for $f_0$. Since $f_0∈(p_f)$ and, obviously, $p_f γ∈(p_f )$ we can assume $f_0=p_f γ  ⇔  f_0=p_a p_b…p_e p_g…p_k β+1$, where $β<p_f$ so as not to wrap around in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$. Such $β∈\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ exists (as was just shown) and is necessarily *unique* (otherwise there would be two distinct factors $f_1 x+f_0$ being mapped to the same $k$-tuple by the isomorphism $π$, a contradiction). 
**Thus (*)**: 
$f_1=p_a p_b…p_e p_g…p_k α$,   where    $α=(p_a p_b…p_e p_g…p_k )^{-1} mod\ p_f$, 
  $f_0=p_a p_b…p_e p_g…p_k β+1$,   where   $β<p_f$  such  that   $f_0∈(p_f )$

---

---

### Part 2

Now let's apply the results obtained to factorization of $x$ in $\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}[x]$ as an example using equations (*).
$30=2\cdot3\cdot5$, where $p_a=2,\ p_b=3,\ p_c=5$ and the number of primes $k=3$. Hence  $x$ has (*Claim 3*) at most $3$ nonconstant linear (*Claim 1*) factors and so up to associates is factorized (*Claim 2*) as $x=(a_1 x+a_0)(b_1 x+b_0)(c_1 x+c_0)$.

$a_1=p_b p_c α$, where $α=(p_b p_c )^{-1} mod\ p_a$, hence $a_1=3\cdot5\cdotα$, where $α=(3\cdot5)^{-1} mod\ 2=(1\cdot1)^{-1}\ mod\ 2=1$, so that  $a_1=3\cdot5\cdot1=15$. 
$a_0=p_b p_c β+1$, where $β<p_a$ such that $a_0∈(p_a)$, hence $a_0=3\cdot5\cdotβ+1$, where $β<2$ such that $a_0=15β+1∈(2)$. Here $β=1$, so that $a_0=3\cdot5\cdot1+1=16∈(2)$. 
Thus, $a_1 x+a_0=15x+16$.

$b_1=p_a p_c α$, where $α=(p_a p_c)^{-1} mod\ p_b$, hence $b_1=2\cdot5\cdotα$, where $α=(2\cdot5)^{-1} mod\ 3=(2\cdot2)^{-1} mod\ 3=1$, so that  $b_1=2\cdot5\cdot1=10$. 
$b_0=p_a p_c β+1$, where $β<p_b$ such that $b_0∈(p_b)$, hence $b_0=2\cdot5\cdotβ+1$, where $β<3$ such that $b_0=10β+1∈(3)$. Here $β=2$, so that $b_0=2\cdot5\cdot2+1=21∈(3)$. 
Thus, $b_1 x+b_0=10x+21$.

$c_1=p_a p_b α$, where $α=(p_a p_b )^{-1} mod\ p_c$, hence $c_1=2\cdot3\cdotα$, where $α=(2\cdot3)^{-1} mod\ 5=1$, so that $c_1=2\cdot3\cdot1=6$. 
$c_0=p_a p_b β+1$, where $β<p_c$ such that $c_0∈(p_c )$, hence $c_0=2\cdot3\cdotβ+1$, where $β<5$ such that $c_0=6β+1∈(5)$. Here $β=4$, so that $c_0=2\cdot3\cdot4+1=25∈(5)$. 
Thus, $c_1 x+c_0=6x+25$.

So, $x=(15x+16)(10x+21)(6x+25)$ in $\Bbb{Z}/30\Bbb{Z}[x]$ — *exactly the same factorization* as given by *Dummit and Foote*. 
It seems that it is the only one factorization with maximal number of $3$ nonconstant factors unique up to multiplication by units (up to associates) according to the [result] of Part 1.

---

As a further example using the same technique (omitting calculations): 
 $x=(5005x+10011)(6006x+9010)(10725x+4291)(1365x+13651)(6930x+8086)$ in $\Bbb{Z}/15015\Bbb{Z}[x]$, where $15015=3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13$. 
It seems that it is the only one factorization with maximal number of $5$ nonconstant factors unique up to multiplication by units (up to associates) according to the [result] of Part 1.

---

---

### Question

Somehow I have doubts on the [result] of Part 1. That is: 
⦁ If $n$ is the product of $k$ distinct primes in $\Bbb{Z}$ *is it always true* that $f(x)=x$ in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}[x]$ has only one factorization with maximal number of nonconstant factors unique up to multiplication by units (up to associates)**?** 
If this is not the case, please, provide a counterexample.

P.S. By "associates" above I mean their usual definition. I know that there are several definitions of "associates" in non-integral domains, but I haven't studied this properly as of yet, so excuse me, please, if this is imprecise.